# ASP.NET MVC: Filtering/Varying by HTTP Status Code in OutputCache Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

In the ASP.NET MVC site that I'm writing, I'm building a generic Error Action that is routed to by an HttpModule, [following this tutorial](http://www.evanclosson.com/devlog/bettercustomerrorsinaspnet). In this Action, I will return a View corresponding to the status code that is applied to the response inside the HttpModule (after doing this, the module transfers the request over to the Action in question).

That's all good, except that I want to implement caching. I don't want to use the `OutputCache` attribute without filtering/varying, because that would mean that the page would be cached once. I want the page to be cached once for every possible status code.

**Is it possible to somehow filter/vary with `OutputCacheAttribute`'s properties, so that each Response.StatusCode is cached separately?**

Comment: Did you find a clean solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How are you currently handling the routing to your error action, e.g. you could have:

```
/Errors/404
/Errors/500
```

All pointing to the exact same action, and the caching will be handled for you because they are independent urls and you apply the OutputCache attribute a single time to the generic error action:

```
[OutputCache]
public ActionResult DisplayError(int errorCode) {
   return View(errorCode.ToString());
}
```

Would that work?